# How long before new quota takes effect

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, quota, google-developers-console

I requested quota increase on the YouTube API though the google developer console from 10k to 100k.

I received a successful email, that says my increase has been approved

[image]

However if i check the UI in Google developer console it still states my quota is 10,000 per day.

[image]

When will my quota increase take effect?

Comment: Can you please share the code you're using or something similar?

Comment: @shapiroyaacov there would be no code associated with this question, as it is related to configuration of usage of the YouTube API for a developer.

Comment: @DaImTo - So sharing the configuration would be useful - as would seem from your answer...

Comment: @shapiroyaacov the only configuration there is is the second image, it shows the settings for the quota in google developer console, this is not something that is configured in code.   If your looking for a project id, i would never ask anyone to share their project id or credentials as its against the TOS for google developers.

Comment: @DaImTo - I see. Ok. Hope your answer helps.

Comment: I don't think you are looking at the correct screen.
It should look like https://imgur.com/cjlKtKN

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The first thing i would do would be check that you are looking at the correct project.   As this quota will be only valid for the project you applied for.

Then you need to edit the quota and increase it yourself.  You should have that option to do that now. If you don't have that option I would wait a couple of days, to see if it doesn't kick in.

You might want to start sending requests and see if the quota increase is actually there its not not appearing in the UI yet.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer~ I checked the project id and it is correct.  It has been a month since the successful approval email has been received. So far, no options have appeared in the project. When I modify the quota, the upper limit is still 10,000. I upload a video through the YOUTUBE data api and it takes about 1600 quotas. When I upload the sixth video, the api still returns an error of insufficient quota.

Comment: You dont have the option to change the number?

Comment: @ DaImTo - I have the option to change number, but the limit is 10,000

Comment: If its been a month then i would send the quota extension reqest again.

Comment: ok, I will send  the quota extension request again.